# Ubuntu: Error NU1301 unable to load the service index for source

Tags: .net, ubuntu, azure-functions, nuget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have created C# project using .Net 6.0 to run Event grid trigger azure function. It is running fine in windows.
I installed Windows subsystem for Linux(WSL) on my Windows 11 OS.
I am using Visual Studio Code. When I ran `dotnet restore` command on wsl terminal, it is giving error - /mnt/c/Code/Code/Test.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://microsoftit.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/**/nuget/v3/index.json.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 distribution for Linux in WSL.
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1301

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when using .NET 6 Preview in WSL. The workaround is to add the Microsoft package source directly in your csproj file:

```
<PackageSource Include="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet6/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

Then run dotnet restore again and it should work.
This issue will be addressed in a future preview update.
Note: You'll also need to install the dotnet-sdk-6.0 Preview in WSL, not just dotnet-sdk.

Update: This issue is now fixed in .NET 6 Preview 4, so you no longer need the workaround. Just install the latest preview and dotnet restore should work without manually adding the package source.

Comment: As a workaround for now, you can add the following to your .csproj file:
`<RestoreSources>
  <Clear />
  <PackageSource>https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json</PackageSource>
</RestoreSources>`

This will instruct NuGet to only use nuget.org as a package source, bypassing the Visual Studio feeds that are currently causing the error.